# Displaying Data in dynamic category and dynamic data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php

i have three categories like Stories,Movie Stories,Photos

i wanna Display Data category wise data from database....like

1.Stories
*data1
*data2
*data3

2.movie stories
*data1
*data2
*data3

controller:

```
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
          $this->load->model('home_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['header_menu'] = $this->home_model->get_header_menu();
    $data['category'] = $this->home_model->get_category();
    $data['home_cat'] = $this->home_model->get_cat_data();

    $this->load->view('home/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('home/homepage');
    $this->load->view('home/footer');
}
```

model:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}

function get_header_menu(){
    $query = $this->db->get('header_menu');
    return $query->result_array();
}


function get_category(){
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query->result_array();
}


function get_cat_data(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->join('home_page','category.id = home_page.c_id','left');
    $this->db->where('category.id = home_page.c_id');

    $this->db->group_by('home_page.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">


    <?php foreach($category as $cate) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th class="success"><?php echo $cate['categories']?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php foreach ($home_cat as $homecat){?>
                                            <a href="#"><?php echo $homecat['category_title']?></a>
                    <hr>
                                            <?php } ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

database:

Create Table
home_page:

CREATE TABLE `home_page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p.id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_title` text,
  `category_url` text,
  `category_image` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

category: 
id int(11) NOT NULL
categories_name text NULL

What I tried, I want to display data by category wise:
[image: What I tried, I want to display data by category wise]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i sent u the picture

Answer (score 0):

its not a exact answer you to enhance this one

you have to filter the values in view page like this

add if condition in each foreach loop to filter the category like this

```
<?php foreach($catagory as $cata) { ?>

<td><?php foreach ($home_cat as $homecat){

        if($cata['id']==$homecat['c_id'])
         {
         //here we filter the value categorywise 
        ?>
         <a href="#"><?php echo $homecat['catagory_title']; ?></a>

      <?php } ?></td>

    <?php   }

   } ?>
```